# How to modify the contents of a zip iterator

Tags: compiler-errors, iterator, zip, thrust

I have the XYZ locations of 1000 points. I need to transform each of them with a matrix. To start with a simpler problem, I try to multiply each point with a constant. Also I take only three points for example. I use thrust::zip_iterator to pack the XYZ and use a functor and transform operation to modify the XYZ.

My code is as below, However it gives compilation error. The functor modify_tuple compiles fine. But when it is used in the transform operation I get lot of errors. **My question is how to modify the contents of a zip iterator ? Or How do I apply the functor to a tuple of type XYZ for all points using thrust. Is there any other thrust algorithm that I can use?**

```
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

typedef thrust::tuple<float,float,float> Float3;

struct modify_tuple
{
    int _factor;
    modify_tuple(int factor) : _factor(factor) { }

    __host__ __device__ Float3 operator()(Float3&a) const
    {
        Float3 b=thrust::make_tuple(_factor*thrust::get<0>(a), _factor*thrust::get<1>(a), _factor*thrust::get<2>(a));      

        return b;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    thrust::device_vector<float> X(3);
    thrust::device_vector<float> Y(3);
    thrust::device_vector<float> Z(3);

    X[0]=0,    X[0]=1,    X[0]=2;
    Y[0]=4,    Y[0]=5,    Y[0]=6;
    Z[0]=7,    Z[0]=8,    Z[0]=9;

    typedef thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator                     FloatIterator;
    typedef thrust::tuple<FloatIterator, FloatIterator, FloatIterator> FloatIteratorTuple;
    typedef thrust::zip_iterator<FloatIteratorTuple>                   Float3Iterator;

    Float3Iterator P_first = thrust::make_zip_iterator(make_tuple(X.begin(), Y.begin(), Z.begin()));
    Float3Iterator P_last  = thrust::make_zip_iterator(make_tuple(X.end(), Y.end(), Z.end()));

// This line gives errors
    thrust::transform(thrust::device, P_first, P_last, P_first, modify_tuple(2));  

    return 0;
}
```

Errors found during compilation:

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/internal_functional.h(322): error: function "modify_tuple::operator()" cannot be called with the given argument list
            argument types are: (thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<float &, float &, float &, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>)
            object type is: modify_tuple
          detected during:
            instantiation of "thrust::detail::enable_if_non_const_reference_or_tuple_of_iterator_references<thrust::tuple_element<1, Tuple>::type>::type thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<UnaryFunction>::operator()(Tuple) [with UnaryFunction=modify_tuple, Tuple=thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<float &, float &, float &, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>, thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<float &, float &, float &, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/function.h(60): here
            instantiation of "Result thrust::detail::wrapped_function<Function, Result>::operator()(const Argument &) const [with Function=thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<modify_tuple>, Result=void, Argument=thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>, thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/for_each.inl(57): here
            instantiation of "void thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_kernel::operator()(thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::parallel_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::concurrent_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::agent<1UL>, 0UL>, 0UL> &, Iterator, Function, Size) [with Iterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, Function=thrust::detail::wrapped_function<thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<modify_tuple>, void>, Size=unsigned int]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/bulk/detail/apply_from_tuple.hpp(71): here
            instantiation of "void thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::apply_from_tuple(Function, const thrust::tuple<Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type> &) [with Function=thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_kernel, Arg1=thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::parallel_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::concurrent_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::agent<1UL>, 0UL>, 0UL> &, Arg2=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, Arg3=thrust::detail::wrapped_function<thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<modify_tuple>, void>, Arg4=unsigned int]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/bulk/detail/closure.hpp(50): here
            instantiation of "void thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::closure<Function, Tuple>::operator()() [with Function=thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_kernel, Tuple=thrust::tuple<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::parallel_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::concurrent_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::agent<1UL>, 0UL>, 0UL> &, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::detail::wrapped_function<thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<modify_tuple>, void>, unsigned int, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/bulk/detail/cuda_task.hpp(58): here
            [ 8 instantiation contexts not shown ]
            instantiation of "RandomAccessIterator thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n(thrust::system::cuda::detail::execution_policy<DerivedPolicy> &, RandomAccessIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::par_t, RandomAccessIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, Size=signed long, UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<modify_tuple>]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/for_each.inl(173): here
            instantiation of "RandomAccessIterator thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each(thrust::system::cuda::detail::execution_policy<DerivedPolicy> &, RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator, UnaryFunction) [with DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::par_t, RandomAccessIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<modify_tuple>]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/for_each.inl(44): here
            instantiation of "InputIterator thrust::for_each(const thrust::detail::execution_policy_base<DerivedPolicy> &, InputIterator, InputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::par_t, InputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<modify_tuple>]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/detail/generic/transform.inl(57): here
            instantiation of "OutputIterator thrust::system::detail::generic::transform(thrust::execution_policy<DerivedPolicy> &, InputIterator, InputIterator, OutputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::par_t, InputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, OutputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, UnaryFunction=modify_tuple]" 
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/transform.inl(44): here
            instantiation of "OutputIterator thrust::transform(const thrust::detail::execution_policy_base<DerivedPolicy> &, InputIterator, InputIterator, OutputIterator, UnaryFunction) [with DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::par_t, InputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, OutputIterator=thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, UnaryFunction=modify_tuple]" 
modify_zip_iterator.cu(38): here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the functor types to match the types passed by thrust and required by thrust can sometimes be tricky.  Here is one possible approach using templating to let the compiler decide the exact type needed:

```
$ cat t334.cu
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

struct modify_tuple
{
    int _factor;
    modify_tuple(int factor) : _factor(factor) { }
template <typename T>
    __host__ __device__ thrust::tuple<float,float,float> operator()(const T a) const
    {
        thrust::tuple<float,float,float>  res = a;
        thrust::get<0>(res) *= _factor;
        thrust::get<1>(res) *= _factor;
        thrust::get<2>(res) *= _factor;
        return res;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    thrust::device_vector<float> X(3);
    thrust::device_vector<float> Y(3);
    thrust::device_vector<float> Z(3);
    thrust::device_vector<float> RX(3);
    thrust::device_vector<float> RY(3);
    thrust::device_vector<float> RZ(3);

    X[0]=0,    X[1]=1,    X[2]=2;
    Y[0]=4,    Y[1]=5,    Y[2]=6;
    Z[0]=7,    Z[1]=8,    Z[2]=9;

    thrust::copy_n(X.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(Y.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(Z.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    thrust::transform(thrust::device, thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(X.begin(), Y.begin(), Z.begin())),thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(X.end(), Y.end(), Z.end())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(RX.begin(), RY.begin(), RZ.begin())), modify_tuple(2));
    thrust::copy_n(X.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(Y.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(Z.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(RX.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(RY.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    thrust::copy_n(RZ.begin(), 3, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t334 t334.cu
$ ./t334
0,1,2,
4,5,6,
7,8,9,
0,1,2,
4,5,6,
7,8,9,
0,2,4,
8,10,12,
14,16,18,
$
```

The exact underlying type passed to the functor appears to be a tuple-of-iterator-references, whereas the return type is an ordinary tuple of `float` values.

Note that it is possible to modify `a` directly in the functor.  It would normally appear that `a` is passed by value to the functor, but in this case thrust is using a tuple-of-iterator-references, and so a side effect of modifying `a` in the functor is that it will modify the actual thrust vector values passed to the functor (i.e. the source vector(s)).  Therefore I have chosen a realization in the above code that avoids this, however in the case of your original code, its evident you intended to do an in-place modification of the source vectors.  Therefore, the functor could be simplified to modify `a` directly, if desired.